# How to use postMessage to listen to events for videojs in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

How would I go about listening to events from a videojs player within an iframe?
I'm tryig to get the play/pause and ended events to work but I dont know how.

Comment: are the main page and iframe code in your control?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes the iframe and main page are in my control

Comment: then what's the problem, use postMessage, although, if they are the same domain, you can just add listeners directly (I could be wrong)

Comment: @JaromandaX I have no idea how I would do that, I know how i would use window.onload, but I want to try it with postMessage

Comment: you've read some documentation about [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)?